# magento event before or after product load from search or home or catalog page

Tags: php, magento, events

I need a magento event/observer which call before/after product loads.
I want to change/append product name by that observer.

I used **catalog_product_load_after event**,

but it does not work, when you load product from search,
and also it does not call to products which are on home page like best selling product etc.

basically a function/observer/event which call every time when product load in magento frontend whether it loads on home page or search page.

Comment: catalog_product_load_after event always called whenever any product load. put a Mage::log($name) in Mage::dispatchEvent() and check its calling or not in your case.

Answer (score 9):

The `catalog_product_load_after` event is valid and will fire every time a product loads.  If it's not firing when you think it should a product isn't loading or the event has been altered by customisations to your store.

Importantly, note that the `catalog_product_load_after` event will **not** fire if you are loading a product collection (as in this case you are of course not loading a product but a collection containing products).  Category and search results pages don't load each product individually but load a filtered product collection which is why you are not seeing the event fire.  You may way to instead consider using the event `catalog_product_collection_load_after` which will allow you to pull the collection and iterate through it from inside the observer method.

```
<?php
class NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function observerMethod($observer)
    {
        foreach ($observer->getCollection() as $product):
            ...
        endforeach;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried this event but does not call on product view page. Its working for all other.

Comment: `catalog_product_collection_load_after` will fire with a call such as `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load()`.  I would suggest you put a listener inside the Mage::dispatchEvent() method using an IDE and xdebug and find out which events fire around the time you are interested in.